# How to extract shortest path from floydwarshall algorithm pgrouting

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, shortest-path

I've tried Floyd-Warshall algorithm using pgrouting with the following code;

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_floydwarshall(
'SELECT gid AS id, 
      source, 
      target, 
      meters AS cost
      FROM jalan')
```

and the result is:
[image: result table from pgadmin]

The question is How to extract path to new table from the result above if the source node = 9 and target node = 24?

Answer (score 1):

First, to filter your result, simply add your required condition to your query. So here, it's your query with the addition `WHERE start_vid = 9 AND end_vid = 24`.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_where_clause.htm) you can find further info on the usage of `WHERE` clauses.

After that, just insert your result into your desired table as explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html).

Comment: I'm able to have a result using where clause as the picture below, 

http://tinypic.com/r/2nkuln8/9

the next question is how can i join the result with road table (geom column) so that it can be visualized in a map/join with geom column?

Comment: You cannot do that using the FloydWarshall, because it doesn't give you the path itself, but only the cost.
See the documentation. http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/allpairs/doc/pgr_floydWarshall.html#pgr-floydwarshall

If you need the path, you can use a path finding algorithm like Dijkstra or A-star.

Comment: I compare some algorithms for my thesis, including floyd-warshall and dijkstra. Is there a way to get the shortest path from floyd-warshall algorithm using pgrouting?

Comment: No there isn't. See the first point of the main characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_floydwarshall(
'SELECT gid AS id, 
  source, 
  target, 
  meters AS cost
  FROM jalan')
  WHERE start_vid = 9 AND end_vid = 24;
```

You were actually computing the shortest path from/to every node you have which was surely taking too much time, you need to add the where clause to you query so you can specify the origin and destination

Comment: I'm able to have a result using where clause as the picture below, 

http://tinypic.com/r/2nkuln8/9

the next question is how can i join the result with road table (geom column) so that it can be visualized in a map?

Comment: you can launch your query from the database manager in qgis this way you import the result directly in the map

Comment: I'm sorry I still didn't get it, because the DB manager asked me to define the unique values and geometry column which is not found in the query result (as attached in pic below). How can I handle this?

http://tinypic.com/r/wtiwjm/9

Comment: I assume that you have a table with the geometries, different from the jalan table, right ? if yes can you post a screenshot of select * from yourTable; please

Comment: I used "jalan" table as my edge_table, the table has gid, cost and of course it has "geom" column. The issue is when I run the floyd warshall query, the result table did not include "geom" and/or "ID" column.
http://tinypic.com/r/hwamia/9

Comment: try adding it in the inner select like this  SELECT * FROM pgr_floydwarshall(
'SELECT gid AS id, 
  source, 
  target, 
  meters AS cost,
  geom
  FROM jalan')
  WHERE start_vid = 9 AND end_vid = 24;

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2z6s3gn/9
still got the same result as the first code, is there any other way?

Comment: ok I see, you need to join the table jalan and the result you got like this :   select * from jalan as a,(SELECT * FROM pgr_floydwarshall( 'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, meters AS cost, geom FROM jalan') WHERE start_vid = 9 AND end_vid = 24) as b where a.source=b.start_vid and a.target=b.end_vid;

Comment: I've tried the code.The results are, all the columns of the table + start_vid, end_vid and agg_cost without a row result for the join process. I assume that the result of FloydWarshall is a direct path from the starting point to the end point (a-b), where in the "jalan" table have no such a pair (a-x, x-y, y-b)